# Get only 2 people to enable video call at a time using agora?

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

Is their anyway to have only have two people who can go on a video call at a time from a room on agora. For example their are 20 speakers, and only 2 people at a time can have their video on, and if one closes their video someone else can turn it on. Is their an API for this, or a method to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The concept you are asking about is achievable using the Agora RTC and RTM SDKs. The Agora RTC (Voice/Video) SDK supports up to 17 active broadcasters/hosts ([*for 128 hosts see FAQ*](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/faq/capacity)) but does not have any methods to limit the number below that. This is where Agora RTM can help, it is a signaling layer that enables client side devices to communicate with string and JSON messages.

I would recommend you take a look at this guide on ["Dynamic Channels"](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/real-time-messaging-and-video-with-dynamic-channels-using-the-agora-flutter-sdk/). It explains how to use RTM to create a lobby where users can see existing channels and either join a channel or create a new one. With some slight modifications, you could add limitations to the number of participants.

Specifically in [this section](https://github.com/Meherdeep/agora-dynamic-video-chat-rooms/blob/2641ac304385f193529e059d290da6c71d0e3d8a/lib/pages/lobby.dart#L91), currently there is a check before joining the call, you can change the `4` to `2` it will say the channel is full and not allow others to join. The `onTap` should look like this:

```
onTap: () {
  // limit channel to 2 people
  if (_channelList.values.toList()[index] <= 2) {
    joinCall(_channelList.keys.toList()[index], _channelList.values.toList()[index]);
  } else {
    print('Channel is full');
  }
},
```